# Visual Studio C# sort fields by type

Tags: c#, visual-studio, resharper, code-formatting

I have a large project in C# and I want to auto-format the code. Currently, I'm using Resharper for this, however I want to sort my fields by their type (so all my ints are together, all my strings are together, etc) and Resharper doesn't seem to have this option. Is there any existing option to do this?

EDIT:

Other plugins I've looked at (like CodeMaid and CodeSorter) don't mention having this ability either. I suppose I could write some flex and yacc as a last resort, but it might be faster to just do it by hand.

As an example, I would turn this code

```
public class MyClass
{
    private int myInt1;
    private string myString1;
    private int myInt2;
    private string myString2;
    private int myInt3;
    private string myString3;
    private int myInt4;
    private string myString4;
    private int myInt5;
    private int myInt6;
    private int myInt7;
}
```

Into this code

```
public class MyClass
{
    #region Instance Variables

    private int myInt1;
    private int myInt2;
    private int myInt3;
    private int myInt4;
    private int myInt5;
    private int myInt6;
    private int myInt7;

    private string myString1;
    private string myString2;
    private string myString3;
    private string myString4;

    #endregion
}
```

Comment: How many fields do you need to sort?

Comment: @Tim Well, all of them. It varies by file, but it could be a few dozen (I just used ints as an example).

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you can do it in ReSharper with a custom Type Members Layout, although it might be a lot of work and be quite verbose:

ReSharper --> Options --> Code Editing --> C# --> Type members layout.